# Appying Background Color to entire line of Text

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, background-color

I have a RichTextBox in a WPF Application. I would like to apply alternate coloring to each lines of texts. I have set the Background property to be of the desired color, but due to differences in text length, only the portion containing text gets the background color. How to set properties so that the entire line is set to the desired background color.

One non-elegant solution is to, pad some spaces, but if RichTextBox layout changes, then the code needs to be changed by trial and error basis.

Any better approach?

Comment: Can you please post your code about how you defined color ?

Comment: Can you explain the user actions? Should I assume this is what you are doing.... 1. Type 3 lines below each other. 2. Select one of the lines and set background color. 3. expect the background to span across the width of the rich text box / horizontal scroll bar for that line?

Comment: @AngelWPF: There won't be any horizontal scroll bar. The width is fixed. It's much like the alternate coloring people do to list to make it less painful to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to know how to make this work with Items generated dynamically. For my actual case, I used extra spaces. For now, this is the way for me to go.

Answer (score 0):

If all the lines are the same height, then you can apply a background graphic to the `RichTextBox` itself, which would have the same effect (set dimensions / colours as appropriate):

```
<RichTexBox>
    <RichTexBox.Background>
            <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0 0 100 100" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <StackPanel>
                       <Rectangle Width="100" Height="50" Fill="Red" />
                       <Rectangle Width="100" Height="50" Fill="Blue" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
    </RichTexBox.Background>
</RichTexBox>
```

Comment: The lines are generated dynamically, so I don't this existing XAML code can be adapted to do the task. Though, I haven't tried the approach you suggested, but will it work for more than 3 lines?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `List` which highlights the rows of lines with a background color. Refresh the `ListItem` collection (according to the number of lines in the text) when anyone changes Text in `RichTextBox.TextChanged` event.

```
    <RichTextBox>
        <RichTextBox.Document>
            <FlowDocument>
                <List>
                    <ListItem Background="Red" />
                    <ListItem Background="Green"/>
                    <ListItem Background="Yellow"/>
                </List>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox.Document>
    </RichTextBox>
```

I think you can change the **bulleted** look n feel of the list by overriding its style.