# Alternate Coloring (BACKCOLOR) for each line in RICHTEXTBOX (NOT FORECOLOR)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have read this article
[Appying Background Color to entire line of Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565471/appying-background-color-to-entire-line-of-text)

This is exactly what i need , but i'm using VB.NET, 
The question is  :
how should i apply that "listitem collection" in VB.NET ?

Any help is appreciated.
Best regards

Comment: Hard to make sense of this question.  RichTextBox is not a great control to display a "listitem collection" or to keep the color consistent while the user is editing text.  It is best done with a ListBox or ListView.  ListView makes it particularly easy to set the ListViewItem.BackColor property.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, i guess you're right, modifying the listitem collection is not a good idea, i've solved the answers and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hans Passant
Yes, You are right, i've changed the code, now it works.

```
    Dim Linez As String() = New String(boxitem.Lines.Length - 1) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To boxitem.Lines.Length - 1
        Linez(i) = boxitem.Lines(i) + New String(" ", 80)
    Next
    boxitem.Clear()
    boxitem.Lines = Linez        
For i As Integer = 0 To boxitem.Lines.Length - 1
        Dim Linez1 As Integer = boxitem.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i)
        boxitem.[Select](Linez1, boxitem.Lines(i).Length)
        boxitem.SelectionBackColor = If((i Mod 2 = 0), Color.MistyRose, Color.Bisque)
    Next
    Try 
boxitem.Select(boxitem.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(boxitem.Lines.Length - 1), 
boxitem.Lines(boxitem.Lines.Length - 1).Length)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```